# How to get the <h1> separated?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I need to split the `<h1>` from the rest of the html code to put it in a modal title. The other html part has to go to the modal-body.

I wrote a bootstrap modal and I get the href, but I don't know how to get the html of the href and split it into title and body.

```
$('.helpicon').click(function() {
    if( $("#helpModal").length == 0) {
        $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="helpboxModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +  
                '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">' +
                    '<div class="modal-content">' +                             
                        '<div class="modal-header">' +
                            '<h5 class="modal-title">           </h5>' +
                            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">' +
                                '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
                            '</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="modal-body">               </div>' +
                        '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
                        '</div>' +                              
                     '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>');
        }
        var modalTitle=$(this).attr('href');
        alert (modalTitle);
        $("#helpModal .modal-title').load(    modal title here   )");
        $("#helpModal .modal-body').load(     modal body here    )");
        $("#helpModal").modal();
        return false;
});
```

I'm thankful for some tips

Comment: Please add the HTML form that you want to split.

Comment: You've mixed up `"` and `'`  `$("#helpModal .modal-title").load(remoteUrl);`  alternatively, if your `h1` is already on the page and is text, then you would use `.text()` not `.load()` - it's unclear what the relevance of `$(this).attr('href');` is

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jquery, so maybe I'm phrasing the question a bit wrong. `$(this).attr('href')`  gives me the url of the page where the info is. This page contains normal html, like: `<div id="content"><h1>My Headline</h1><p>Some text</p></div>`
How i can read the html code of this page (or another info page) and get the html of the `<div id="content">`,  seperate the <h1> into the modal-header and the rest in the modal-body. All the html of the page is written into the modal body with this code `$('#helpboxModal .modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));`

Thanks :-)